# Is there a way to run code after knockoutjs render only knowing the binding context?

Tags: magento, knockout.js, binding, render

I'm working on a module in a CMS' backend.  I'm trying to 'hook in' to their knockout bindings and run code when they are finished rendering.  So far I've had no luck.

I have however, attached to the different data-components and obtained knockout data.

I've had many failed attempts, but so far, I have this which is returning a binding context.

```
var bindingContext = ko.contextFor(jQuery('div[data-component="customer_form.areas"]').get(0));
```

Does anyone know of a way I can use this to somehow attach an observer to watch for the rendering to finish?  I'll admin, I'm new to knockout.  I'm not creating the view models, nor the templates.  I can't add the afterRender to the template like I think *should* be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you said, this *should* be done using `afterRender`. All other methods feel hacky, because you'll never know when knockout will re-render (parts of) the ui.

I can't think of a reason why you'd need such a work around, but who am I to judge..

The only approach I can think off, is to use the `MutationObserver`. Here's an example:

```js
var bindingContextElement = document.querySelector("ul");

var renderThrottle = 300;
var renderCycle = null;
var onRenderComplete = function() {
  var pre = document.createElement("pre");
  var msg = new Date().toLocaleString() + ": finished rendering";
  pre.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg));
  document.body.appendChild(pre);
}

// Observe mutations to element, call onRenderComplete after 300ms of no mutations
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  clearTimeout(renderCycle);
  renderCycle = setTimeout(onRenderComplete, renderThrottle);
});

var config = {
  childList: true
};

observer.observe(bindingContextElement, config);

ko.applyBindings({
  items: ko.observableArray([1, 2, 3])
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
  <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>

<button data-bind="click: function() { items.push(items().length + 1)}">add</button>
```

This code listens to any mutations in the `<ul>` element, which is controlled by knockout. Once changes start happening to the element or its children, it attempts to log a "Rendered" message. It's only allowed to log this message if there are no further changes for 300ms.

Have a look at [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to determine your `config` object and which elements to watch... And please keep in mind that things might get out of hand if stuff gets more complicated than this example...

Comment: Will providing a parent node of multiple child bound nodes cause this to fire on each?  I'm testing on one of my uppermost parents to try to catch child updates, but the onRenderComplete isn't firing off.

Comment: I just read the docs, like you said.  subtree: true causes it to fire.  Excellent work. I know its a hackish thing, but sometimes working with a CMS means you can't override core or break the CI / upgrade cycle.